# How to create columns names in MySQL using Python from CSV file?

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I usually work with large CSV data sets. Opening these files take a hell lot of time. My plan is to directly load the csv files without accessing them but am getting an error while creating the table to load the data.

```
import string
import csv
import mysql.connector
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="password")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
with open(r"C:\Users\rcsid\Documents\Office Programs\Working prog\MOCK_DATA.csv") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'create table rd.data ( {" varchar(50), ".join(row)} varchar(50))')
            mycursor.execute(f'create table rd.data ( {" varchar(50), ".join(row)}) varchar(50))')
            line_count += 1
        line_count += 1
```

The print statement is giving the following results:

> create table rd.data ( id varchar(50), first_name varchar(50), last_name varchar(50), email varchar(50), boole varchar(50), coin varchar(50))

The above statement seems correct
But the execute statement is throwing an error:

> ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') varchar(50))' at line 1

This is the starting part. The full program will have many other checks. Wanted to know how to solve this error?
PS: New to Python

Comment: I tested the `create table` statement you show above, and it has no error. I suggest the error is coming from some other SQL statement.

Comment: @Siddhartha-roy-choudhury which server type (e.g. mariadb, mysql) and version of that server are you running? It might make it easier to reproduce the issue for some...

Comment: MySQL 8.0 and Python 3.

That's the only SQL statement I am running for now.

Comment: I think the issue is with the Python command which I am using to create the table. 
mycursor.execute(f'create table rd.data ( {" varchar(50), ".join(row)}) varchar(50))')

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by creating a string statement:

```
sql_str=f'create table rd.data ( {" varchar(50), ".join(row)} varchar(50))'
mycursor.execute(sql_str)
```

This resolved the issue.